# Installed React for the first time and web page won't auto reload when file changes

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I just installed create-react-app for the first time and the page isn't auto-refreshing as it should. I don't know why it's working and I don't have any code to show you because I'm just using the react template. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what exactly did you do? i mean, did you start working with https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html or did you started something on your own?

please describe in full what command did you type.

Comment: I suggest you to check [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started).

Comment: All I did was `npx create-react-app my-app` `cd my-app`  and then `npm start`

Comment: When you edip app.js and save, doesn't it reload?

Comment: No, it doesn't reload at all

Answer (score 0):

be sure webpack-dev-server installed in your new project if not install it :

```
npm i webpack-dev-server
```

if installed see console and check no any error on webpack-dev-server or signal listening [ws]

if you are using in https mode need some manual changing in webpack-dev-server